# Move entire docker project to another machine

Tags: docker, migration

I have a project created with docker, that creates several dockers.

In this project I have data that I don't want to lose, like images, a database, and so on.

I have seem several methods to move it and apparently the best one not to lose data is moving the entire /var/lib/docker to and copy on the other machine.

I have tried to zip it but I am running out problems. How could I perform this task I need to do?

There is a screenshot:

[image]

The project I want to move is this one, in case that helps: https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo

I want to know, afterwards, if moving the entire /var/lib/docker and then, by downloading the git and with a new fresh docker-compose, will work correctly, if I need to change the ownership of the files or what steps.

Regards!

Comment: are you aware that you're missing the all point of docker by that? what about shipping your images?

Comment: "creates several dockers" - are you talking about the images or the containers?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of docker is shipping images by pushing/pulling them to/from remote registries, such as [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/), that's why it was relatively easy for you to start running the up with 2 commands:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Note that while docker images are immutable, there are [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) that can be mount to the host machine for persistency.

So in your case, if you want to copy the persistence data between your hosts, you can simply copy those volumes, for example the [./docker/extra_settings](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L41) directory that was created in your current directory.